# Access Class Variable from outside class RUBY

Tags: ruby, class, variables

I can't seem to figure this out. I have the following class:

```
class CSV_Email

  attr_accessor :client_array, :email_array

  def load(file)
    @file = file
    #Parse csv file into ruby arrays...
    #Column Headers - Email, Client

    @client_array = []
    @email_array = []

    CSV.foreach(file, :col_sep => ",", :headers => :first_row, :return_headers => false) do |column|
      client_array << column[0]
      email_array << column[1]
    end
  end
end
```

Now I need to access `client_id_array` and `email_array`. I tried this:

```
test = CSV_Email.new
test.load("Email_Test.csv")
puts client_array
```

But I receive a `undefined local variable client_array` error. How can I access that variable?

I am using ruby 1.9.3.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the object you created:

```
puts test.client_array
```

Comment: This is possible because `attr_accessor` provides an accessor method.